# Multidimensional Matrix Lookup, how to improve slow solution

Tags: r, for-loop

Sometimes I want to transform several data columns (usually character or factor) into one new column (usually a number). I try to do this using a lookup matrix. For example, my dataset is

```
dset <- data.frame(
   x=c("a", "a", "b"),
   y=c("v", "w", "w"),
   stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)
lookup <- matrix(c(1:4), ncol=2)
rownames(lookup) <- c("a", "b")
colnames(lookup) <- c("v", "w")
```

Ideally (for my purpose here), I would now do

```
transform(dset, z=lookup[x,y])
```

and get my new data column. While this works in the one-dimensional case, this fails here, as `lookup[x,y]` returns a matrix. I came up with this function, which looks rather slow:

```
fill_from_matrix <- function(m, ...) {
  arg <- list(...)
  len <- sapply(arg, length)
  if(sum(diff(len))!=0) stop("differing lengths in fill_from_matrix")
  if(length(arg)!=length(dim(m))) stop("differing dimensions in fill_from_matrix")
  n <- len[[1]]
  dims <- length(dim(m))
  res <- rep(NA, n)
  for (i in seq(1,n)) {
    one_arg <- list(m)
    for (j in seq(1,dims)) one_arg[[j+1]] <- arg[[j]][[i]]
    res[i] <- do.call("[", one_arg)
  }
  return(res)
}
```

With this function, I can call `transform` and get the result I wanted:

```
transform(dset, z=fill_from_matrix(lookup,x,y))
#   x y z
# 1 a v 1
# 2 a w 3
# 3 b w 4
```

However, I am not satisfied with the code and wonder if there is a more elegant (and faster) way to perform this kind of transformation. How do I get rid of the for loops?

Comment: Do you always have a lookup matrix with column and row names? How do you create it? It seems very tedious job to create such a matrix

Comment: In this particular case, it is an input file (CSV) with parameters kept separate from the code to allow later adaption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really quite easy and I suspect fast with base R indexing because the "[" function accepts a two-column matrix for this precise purpose:

```
> dset$z <- lookup[ with(dset, cbind(x,y)) ]
> dset
  x y z
1 a v 1
2 a w 3
3 b w 4
```

If you needed it as a specific function then:

```
lkup <- function(tbl, rowidx, colidx){ tbl[ cbind(rowidx, colidx)]}
zvals <- lkup(lookup, dset$x, dset$y)
zvals
#[1] 1 3 4
```

(I'm pretty sure you can also use three and four column matrices if you have arrays of those dimensions.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use library `dplyr` for `inner_join` and use a `data.frame` instead of `matrix` as lookup table:

```
library(dplyr)

lookup = transform(expand.grid(c('a','b'),c('v','w')), v=1:4) %>%
           setNames(c('x','y','val'))

inner_join(dset, lookup, by=c('x','y'))

#  x y val
#1 a v   1
#2 a w   3
#3 b w   4
```

A fast way is also to use `data.table` package, with my definition of `lookup`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(lookup)
setDT(dset)

setkey(lookup, x ,y)[dset]

#   x y val
#1: a v   1
#2: a w   3
#3: b w   4
```

If for any reason you have your matrix `lookup` as input, transform it in a `dataframe`:

```
lookup = transform(expand.grid(rownames(lookup), colnames(lookup)), v=c(lookup))
names(lookup) = c('x','y','val')
```

Comment: `expand.grid` is also a `for` loop wrapped up in a function similar to OPs. It would be interesting to see of your solution would more efficient on a read data set.

Comment: That's beeing peecky for nothing since the main problematic is to `join` fast and in any case you can replace `expand.grid` by `exp.grid.2 = function(vec1, vec2) {
  data.frame(cbind(Var1=rep(vec1, length(vec2)), Var2=rep(vec2, each=length(vec1))))
}` :)

Comment: I'm not being peeky. `expand.grid` is a very slow function and I'm just stating a fact. You could improve it using `CJ` from `data.table`. Also using `data.frame` instead of a `matrix` is usually bad practice when looking for speed. I don't know where is the bottleneck of this operation as I haven't tested it.